# Sufficient condition for uniform (Lebesgue) integrability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, uniform-integrability

This exercise is from Bass's book on graduate real analysis. I am stuck in one question.

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure and $\sup_n \int |f_n|^{1+\gamma} d\mu<\infty$ for any $\gamma > 0$. Then, $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable.

Uniformly integrable means that, for any $\epsilon$, there is a $M$ such that $\int_{\{x:|f_n(x)|>M\}} |f_n(x)|d\mu < \epsilon$.

By definition, in the sets we are integrating over, we get that $$|f_n(x)|>M\geq0 \to \frac{|f_n(x)|}{M} > 1\to\frac{|f_n(x)|^{1+\gamma}}{M^\gamma} > 1$$

So the integral is bounded as follows:

$$\int_{\{x:|f_n(x)|>M\}}|f_n(x)| d\mu < \frac{1}{M^\gamma} \int_{\{x:|f_n(x)|>M\}} |f_n(x)|^{1+\gamma}d\mu$$
$$\leq \sup_n \left[ \frac{1}{M^\gamma} \int_{\{x:|f_n(x)|>M\}}|f_n(x)|^{1+\gamma} d\mu \right] = \frac{1}{M^\gamma} \sup_n \left[  \int_{\{x:|f_n(x)|>M\}}|f_n(x)|^{1+\gamma} d\mu \right]$$
$$\leq \frac{1}{M^\gamma} \sup_n \left[ \int |f_n(x)|^{1+\gamma} d\mu\right] < \infty$$

Thus,

$$\int_{\{x:|f_n(x)|>M\}}|f_n(x)| d\mu < \frac{1}{M^\gamma} \sup_n \left[  \int_{\{x:|f_n(x)|>M\}}|f_n(x)|^{1+\gamma} d\mu \right] < \infty$$

My problem is picking the $\epsilon$ that will give an $M$ such that the above is true.

Can I just let

$$M = M(\epsilon) = \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon} \sup_n \left[\int |f_n(x)|^{1+\gamma} d \mu \right] \right)^{1/\gamma}$$

?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon> 0$. Choose $M > \frac 1\epsilon\sup_n\int|f_n|^2\,d\mu$. Then, for all $n$,
$$
\int_{\{|f_n|>M\}}|f_n|\,d\mu\,\le\frac 1M\int_{\{|f_n|>M\}}|f_n|^2\,d\mu\,\le\,\epsilon.
$$

Comment: Can I let $M$ be what I defined above?

Comment: Yes, you can. There are many possibilities.